# SQL Server Failover Cluster setup shared drive issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to complete an SQL install on a two node cluster which has three LUNs  assigned from Filer storage present and currently owned by the first node.

I've selected the "New SQL Server failover cluster installation" option from the setup media and got to the "Instance Configuration" step.

Here I've named the SQL Server Network Name and instance and chosen the LUN I;ve dedicated to the DB Data (H:\MSSQL10_50.SQL_DevInst1), however, when I click on **next** I get the following error:

> Instance directory (or command line option /INSTANCEDIR) value for a cluster installation cannot be a directory on shared drive.

I'm baffled by this as the LUN is not a shared drive!

Choosing an actual local drive (C:) does allow this to continue but surely should accept my first choice?

Comment: The installation has to be local you gonna install the sql server instance in all  servers member of the cluster but the database you will put at the share storage
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1782284-1549-1.aspx

Comment: Believe it or not this was the next thing for me to try but just didn't feel right. Turns out it was though. Thanks for the confirmation though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following on another forum which confirmed my hesitation. Should have just gone with my gut.....:

> The root directory has to be on the local drive on each node. There will be 
>   options to specify data and log directories later on in the installation process.

This was also confirmed by Krismorte above.